# ¿Cómo acceder a un nodo XML condicionalmente si existe determinado nodo al mismo nivel?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Tengo el siguiente trozo de código en PHP:

```
$KEY = $carga->xpath(
  '/MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/descriptiveKeywords/MD_Keywords'
);
$KeyWord = $carga->xpath(
  '/MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/descriptiveKeywords/MD_Keywords/keyword'
);
$THESAUR = $carga->xpath(
  '/MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/descriptiveKeywords/MD_Keywords/thesaurusName/CI_Citation/title'
);
```

Como se puede ver tengo dentro de `MD_Keywords` 2 etiquetas hijo posibles. Lo que pretendo es que, si encuentra la etiqueta `thesaurusName`, ejecute determinada acción sobre la etiqueta vecina (del mismo nivel) `keyword` y, en caso contrario (que dentro de `MD_Keywords` solo este el elemento hijo `keyword` sin el de `thesaurusName`), ejecute otra acción distinta.

Hay que tener en cuenta que la etiqueta 'padre' `MD_Keywords` se repite muchas veces a lo largo del XML explorado (este trozo de código se encuentra dentro de un bucle `while`) y es por ello que necesito realizar algún tipo de condición atendiendo a sus etiquetas hijas.

Gracias.

EDITADO: Fragmento XML que contiene las palabras clave:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MD_Metadata>
    <identificationInfo>
        <MD_DataIdentification>
            <descriptiveKeywords>
                <MD_Keywords>
                    <keyword>EQUIPAMIENTOS</keyword>
                    <type>theme</type>
                    <thesaurusName>
                        <CI_Citation>
                            <title>GEMET</title>
                            <identifier>
                                <MD_Identifier>
                                    <authority>
                                        <CI_Citation/>
                                    </authority>
                                </MD_Identifier>
                            </identifier>
                        </CI_Citation>
                    </thesaurusName>
                </MD_Keywords>
            </descriptiveKeywords>
            <descriptiveKeywords>
                <MD_Keywords>
                    <keyword>ordenación del territorio</keyword>
                </MD_Keywords>
            </descriptiveKeywords>
        </MD_DataIdentification>
    </identificationInfo>
</MD_Metadata>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ponernos un ejemplo de XML para poder reproducir tu problema? Trabajar a ciegas a veces nos confunde más que ayuda. ¿Necesitas que se haga todo con una única búsqueda xpath o se puede programar?. Gracias.

Comment: Se puede programar, pero contra mas sencillo sea mejor XD

Answer (score 0):

Primero podrías facilitar el XML, o un fragmento del mismo, puede hacer más fácil la resolución del problema.
Segundo te voy a poner solo el Xpath, en una forma acortada, equivalente a tus queries, siempre que no haya nodos MD_Keywords a un nivel superior.

```
'/MD_Metadata//MD_Keywords'
'/MD_Metadata//MD_Keywords/keyword'
'/MD_Metadata//MD_Keywords/thesaurusName/CI_Citation/title'
```

Bueno, ¿tienes que saber si se encuentra algún nodo "thesaurusName", correcto? Prueba con:

```
'/MD_Metadata//MD_Keywords/count( thesaurusName )'
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, pero usando el count dentro del xpath me salta un error que dice que falla la evaluación en esa linea. Ahora estoy probando si con algun tipo de array diff puedo encontrar difenencias entre los que contienen el nodo 'thesaurusName' y los que no pero aún no encuentro el resultado que necesito.  He editado el post, he añadido un fragmento representativo del XML por que es muy largo.

Comment: Con el xml editado que te puse arriba y la consulta que te he sugerido la query que te he puesto me devuelve 1 (Usando eXist para consultar directamente), creo que el error no seria por la instrucción, de todos modos prueba NO usando la versión acortada:
'/MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/descriptiveKeywords/MD_Keywords/count(thesaurusName)'

Comment: Al final no encontre solución directa, estoy probando combinando DOMElement y SimpleXML utilizando dom_import_simplexml para convertir de SimpleXML a DOM... Avisare si encuentro resultados claros, gracias por su tiempo